# nodejs events is being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I have been working on an CMS on nodejs hosted at https://github.com/techunits/mopublish/tree/develop. Here I have added few event hooks e.g.

```
mpObj.emit('MP:FOOTER', '<center>MPTEST Plugin loaded successfully.</center>');
```

When I handle this event at:

```
mpObj.on("MP:FOOTER", function(str) {
                        console.log(str);
                        if(str) {
                            httpResponse.locals.siteFooter += str;
                        }
});
```

It's getting executed multiple times in 1 page. The pattern as follows:

1. If page is loaded first time it will be executed once.
2. If page is loaded second time it will be executed twice.
3. If page is loaded n times it will be executed n times.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your CMS works, but I suppose the listener is being registered multiple times. Try adding a `mpObj.off("MP:FOOTER");` or the corresponding function in your CMS before the `mpObj.on()` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured that out lately.